# Flutter iOS accessibility focus issue while moving pages with PreloadPageView.builder()

Tags: flutter, accessibility

We are currently working on implementing an accessibility feature for individuals with visual impairments using Flutter. However, we have encountered an issue while transitioning from one page to another within our app. Our approach involves using the PreloadPageView.builder() widget to navigate between these pages.

Unfortunately, we're experiencing a problem where the accessibility focus, indicated by a rectangular border, is not consistently appearing or is being lost when moving to the second page. This is in contrast to the behaviour on the first page, where the accessibility focus works as expected. Strangely, the VoiceOver functionality seems to be consistently staying on the first page rather than moving to the second and third pages. It's worth noting that this issue is specific to iOS, as the feature works perfectly fine on Android without any problems.

And the below are the versions which we are using for flutter and preload_page_view,

```
sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
preload_page_view: ^0.1.6
```

And here is the sample code,

```
PreloadPageView.builder(
         itemCount: 3,
         physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
         onPageChanged: (int postion) {},
         preloadPagesCount: 3,
         controller: _preloadPageController,
         itemBuilder: (context, index){
           if (index == 0) {
             return Dashboard();
           } else if (index == 1) {
             return MyPage();
           }
           else if (index == 2) {
             return Profile();
           }
         }
     ),
```